# How did TechCrunch get in my notifications center?

Tags: macos, notifications, apns

I have begun to see notifications from TechCrunch when they publish articles.

My notifications center is full of the settings for **extremely useful** applications (Calendar, Evernote, Maps, Skype, Dropbox), and then… *a website I sometimes read*.

I can easily set their notifications to "None" but I want:

1. To know how they got there in the first place. I'm sure I never opted in to this.
2. How to completely remove it from my system

Anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if you have desktop notifications enabled in Safari. Go to **Safari Preferences > Notifications**. If the site is listed in there, remove it.[image]

Comment: that was it, thanks. interesting that it was there, because I don't remember ever reading techcrunch on safari (I dont use it much). any idea how it would have gotten there?